# 3D scene doesn't have shadows even though I enabled castShadow and receiveShadow

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

[Enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqiYJ.png)

Hi,

I have an issue with my shadow. I am enabling the shadow in the code, but I don't know why my 3D model is not receiving this shadow. You can see the image or the link [Codesandbox Sunlight](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/sunlight-7yrqph?file=%2Fsrc%2FScene.js%3A19%2C1)

Model.js

```
return <primitive object={scene} receiveShadow />;
```

Scene.js

```
  <directionalLight
    intensity={0.5}
    castShadow // highlight-line
    shadow-mapSize-height={512}
    shadow-mapSize-width={512}
    position={calc}
  />
  <Model />
  {/* Plane just to see the shadow - I will remove it later */}
  <Plane
    receiveShadow // highlight-line
    rotation={[-Math.PI / 2, 0, 0]}
    position={[0, -10, 0]}
    args={[100, 100]}
  >
    <meshStandardMaterial attach="material" color="white" />
  </Plane>
```

I enabled receiveShadow and castShadow